# dig.el broken when invoking with type? How to fix?

Tags: commands

Running emacs 26.1 on window using bind tools x64 9.13.

When I M-x dig `heise.de MX` it seems the question gets mangled:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.13.0 <<>> heise.de MX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 33985
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;heise.de\032MX.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           2748    IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018061001 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 80 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Jun 10 21:35:46 ope 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 115
```

But when I cmd.exe `dig heise.de MX` I get the correct output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.13.0 <<>> heise.de MX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34942
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;heise.de.                      IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
heise.de.               86400   IN      MX      10 relay.heise.de.

;; Query time: 62 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Jun 10 22:36:13 W. Europe Daylight Time 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59
```

How do I fix this? Or is it just an input syntax error on my side? I tried multiple variants but I always end up with this "\032" in emacs.

Comment: The `(interactive ...)` form in the `dig` function doesn't handle optional arguments, so the way to pass them would be to do `M-: (dig "heise.de" "MX")`.  I don't know why it is like this.  Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your "workaround" is good enough, it enables me to use it inside emacs. I think I'll post it on the emacs mailing list for investigation.